# Dynamically adding images based on browser theme

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a test website which dynamically changes it's look based on what theme the browser is in. I have been trying to make certain images be used if browser themes are different, to match the rest of the webpage. I have some js code to handle this.

```
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];
            var link = document.createElement('link');

            var imgToAppend = document.createElement('img');

            imgToAppend.alt = 'A Test Logo';

            link.rel = 'stylesheet'; 
            link.type = 'text/css';

            if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
                link.href = 'css/dark-theme.css';
                imgToAppend.src = 'Test-Image-Dark.jpg';
            }
            if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: light)').matches) {
                link.href = 'css/light-theme.css';
                imgToAppend.src = 'Test-Image.jpg';
            }

            imgToAppend.id = 'Main-Img';
            head.appendChild(link);
            document.getElementById('ImgDiv').appendChild(imgToAppend);
```

However, this does not work. When I launch the program, no image appears, and the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null` appears instead.

I have tried a lot to fix it, but I'm still not sure what's up with it or how to fix it.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just for clarity, ImgDiv is the id of the div that I want the image in.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have any element with the id `ImgDiv`. Make sure it exists and you don't have any typos. 
(`appendChild` of null -> you tried to access the method `appendChild` of a variable which is null. So either `head` or `document.getElementById('ImgDiv')` is null)

Comment: @Xenon if you DO have the element with the ImgDiv id, make sure your code is executed after the element is available in the DOM (i.e. right before `</body>` tag).

Comment: @Hanlet Escaño Thanks. Tried it out, and it worked great, thanks!